# How to restrict foreign keys in Rails' update controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

In my Rails app I have `invoices` which in turn can have many `projects`.

**model:**

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :project_id

end
```

**controller:**

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authorized_user, :only => [ :show, :edit, :destroy ]
  before_filter :authorized_project, :only => [ :create, :update ]

  def create # safe
    @invoice = @project.invoices.build(params[:invoice])  
    if @invoice.save
      flash[:success] = "Invoice saved."
      redirect_to edit_invoice_path(@invoice)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update # not safe yet
    if @invoice.update_attributes(params[:invoice])
      flash[:success] = "Invoice updated."
      redirect_to edit_invoice_path(@invoice)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

    def authorized_user
      @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path unless current_user?(@invoice.user)
    end

    def authorized_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:invoice][:project_id])
      redirect_to root_path unless current_user?(@project.user)
    end

end
```

My biggest concern is that a malicious user might, one day, create an `invoice` that belongs to the `project` of another user.

Now thanks to the help of some people on this board I managed to come up with a `before_filter` that makes sure that this won't happen when a project is **created**.

The problem is I don't understand how to apply this filter to the `update` action as well.

Since the update action does not make use of Rails' `build` function, I simply don't know how to get my `@project` in there.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would start from `current_user`, not `@project` (provided `User` `has_many :invoices`):

```
current_user.invoices.build(params[:invoice])
```

Also instead of explicitly check `current_user?(@invoice.user)` you can do:

```
def find_invoice
  @invoice = current_user.invoices.find(params[:id])
end

def find_project
  @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:invoice][:project_id])
end
```

Wrong invoice or project will throw 500 which you may or may not want to handle.

If `User` `has_many :invoices, :through => :projects` and `Project` hence `has_many :invoices` then:

```
def find_invoice
  @invoice = @project.invoices.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Don't forget to rescue from any ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound errors that might occur here.

Comment: @tadman In a simple case I don't care if malicious user gets 500. But in general rescuing is required (e. g. user can access deleted invoice from a stale index page).

Comment: Ah I think I finally got this working. Took me quite a while to get to grips with it though. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `@project.invoices.build` method creates a new `Invoice` that is automatically associated with that particular `@project`. You don't have to do any work, and there's no risk of it being linked to the wrong project.

You'll want to be sure that `project_id` is not an accessible attribute, though.

Comment: I know that. I am not worried about the `build` method. I am worried about my `update` action. Right now, it is possible to hack it and replace the `project_id` with a `project_id` that belongs to another user. I am using a select box to display a user's `project_id`s in the form. I cannot remove `project_id` from accessible because the user can't change it anymore then.

Comment: You should remove it from the accessible list and assign it in a separate pass that validates the user is allowed to make that assignment. `@invoice.project_id = project_id` only when you've verified that the project is theirs.

Comment: What do you mean by `separate pass`?

Comment: As in you do your update as: `@invoice.attributes = params` then `@invoice.project_id = project_id` when you've verified `project_id` is okay. Then `@invoice.save!` Either that or just verify that `params[:project_id]` is okay.